How to determine which column caused an error
I have a data.frame with many list columns.
df <-
  tibble::tibble(
    a = list(c(1,2), c(3,4)),
    b = list(c(1, 2), 'a')
  ) 

I would like to unnest() all of them at once.  However, one of them is problematic.
tidyr::unnest(df, everything())
#> Error in `list_unchop()`:
#> ! Can't combine `x[[1]]` <double> and `x[[2]]` <character>.
#> Backtrace:
#>      x
#>   1. +-tidyr::unnest(df, everything())
#>   2. +-tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(df, everything())
#>   3. | \-tidyr::unchop(...)
#>   4. |   \-tidyr:::df_unchop(...)
#>   5. |     \-vctrs::list_unchop(col, ptype = col_ptype)
#>   6. \-vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
#>   7.   \-vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
#>   8.     +-base::withRestarts(...)
#>   9.     | \-base (local) withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
#>  10.     |   \-base (local) doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
#>  11.     \-vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
#>  12.       \-vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
#>  13.         \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
#>  14.           \-rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = call)

How can I determine which column caused the error without repeatedly removing one and re-rerunning the code?  Is it somewhere in the backtrace?
Created on 2024-06-04 with reprex v2.0.2

It’s not a single column that causes the error, it’s the combination of the two.

@Limey I'm not sure I follow.   If I remove b, the code runs fine.  If I remove a, it still doesn't work.  Doesn't that mean that b alone is the issue?  No column that I add or remove would remove the error unless I remove b.

That’s because ‘bis a list containing two data types: numeric and character. You could combineaandb, or just unnest b` alone, by converting everything to character.

@Limey I know why the error occurs in the example above, but suppose there were 100 columns.  I'm looking for a quick way to determine the column that caused the error.

Possibly relevant, but it's impossible to be sure without knowing your desired output.

The question really being asked is how to identify which list columns contain incompatible types, where other answers so far identify which list columns contain different types. These are obviously separate questions.
Information on the rules for vector compatibility of the fundamental vectors in the tidyverse context can be found in help("faq-compatibility-types", package = vctrs) which gives the following:

Two vectors are compatible when you can safely:

Combine them into one larger vector.

Assign values from one of the vectors into the other vector.


In general, the common type is the richer type, in other words the
type that can represent the most values. Logical vectors are at the
bottom of the hierarchy of numeric types because they can only
represent two values (not counting missing values). Then come integer
vectors, and then doubles. Here is the vctrs type hierarchy for the
fundamental vectors:


Even more detail is provided in help("theory-faq-coercion", package = vctrs).
The function vctrs::vec_ptype_common() identifies whether a set of vectors can be cast to a common type by returning the common type or, if not, an error.  By wrapping this function with purrr::possibly() to return NULL instead of an error, list columns can be checked to see if they contain incompatible types.
library(vctrs)
library(purrr)

incompatible <- function(df) {
  map_lgl(df, \(x) if (is.list(x)) is.null(do.call(possibly(vec_ptype_common, otherwise = NULL), x)) else FALSE)
}

incompatible(df)

    a     b 
FALSE  TRUE 


I was just thinking about this exact issue and added to my answer, but just saw your post. Do you think my addition is too similar? If so, I am happy to delete it as I think this is the correct answer.

@LMc - they're essentially the same answer but I don't mind you keeping it up as a one-less-dependency alternative.

This will iterate over your list-columns and check if all elements in the list are the same proto-type (proto-types being what unnest is based on)1:
library(purrr)
library(vctrs)
library(dplyr)


df |> 
  summarize(across(where(\(x) is(x, "list")), \(x) n_distinct(map(x, vec_ptype)) == 1L))
#   a     b    
#   <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 TRUE  FALSE

You can then easily use these logical values to subset the columns:
df |> 
  summarize(across(where(\(x) is(x, "list")), \(x) n_distinct(map(x, vec_ptype)) == 1L)) |>
  select(where(\(x) !x))
#   b    
#   <lgl>
# 1 FALSE


A separate option would be to actually attempt to cast the column to a common type and if it fails return FALSE:
library(dplyr)
library(vctrs)

try_cast <- function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    vec_ptype_common(!!!x)
    TRUE
  }, error = function(e) FALSE)
}

df |>
  summarize(across(where(\(x) is(x, "list")), try_cast))
#   a     b    
#   <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 TRUE  FALSE

1 Credit to @lotus for correction about using identical.

If you ant to know which are the good columns, the double sapply instruction below will create a numeric vector of lengths. These lengths tell how many different classes do the lists have. If only one, the column is good.
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble::tibble(
    a = list(c(1,2), c(3,4)),
    b = list(c(1, 2), 'a')
  ) 

ok <- sapply(df, \(x) sapply(x, class) |> unique() |> length()) == 1L
df[ok] |> unnest(everything())
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>       a
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
#> 4     4
Ȁ
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'Ȁ' not found

Created on 2024-06-04 with reprex v2.1.0

Unnest all of the variables at once using across and tidy?select everything
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) purrr::map(x, ~ as.character(.x)))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(everything(), names_sep="")
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  a1    a2    b1    b2   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     2     1     2    
2 3     4     a     NA


df <-
  tibble::tibble(
    a = list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(5, 6)),
    b = list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c('a', 'b')),
    c = list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(TRUE, FALSE)),
    d = list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4, 5, 6))
  ) 
colnames(df[which(map_lgl(df, ~length(unique(map(., class ))) > 1) == TRUE)])
[1] "b" "c"


Here is an attempt to fish out the error column, assuming you want all your list columns to contain only numeric values:
fault_detector <- function(df){
  # check if all list columns contain numeric values
  bool <- list()
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    bool[[i]] <- lapply(df[[i]],is.numeric)
  }
  # get index position of df list columns
  index <- 0
  index_pos <- c()
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    index <- index + 1
    index_pos <- c(index_pos,index)
  }
  
  # collect the column that contains the anomaly
  bad_col <- list()
  for(i in index_pos){
    if(all(bool[[i]]) != TRUE){
      bad_col[[i]] <- df[[i]]
    }
  }
  
  return(bad_col)
  
  
}


anomaly <- suppressWarnings(fault_detector(df = df))

print(anomaly)

Output:
[[1]]
NULL
    
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2
    
[[2]][[2]]
[1] "a"

The code finds the anomalous column and returns it as a list. I hope this helps!
